# Multiplying all elements in one array by respective element of a second arrary

Tags: python, arrays, list, element

Hey guys so i want to figure out how to multiply for example, if we have a string of [1,2,3,4] and another of [2,3,4,6], how do you multiply 1*2, 2*3, 3*4....so its each element of an array by the respective one of the second one? I also have these lists in float form if that makes it easier. My friend had suggested:

```
    file5 = open("New_list3",'r+')
    for line in file3:
        mult = float(line.strip())*float(file4.readline().strip())
        file5.write(mult+'\n')
```

Where file3 = the list of numerical string all on separate lines and file 4 the same but different values but that didn't work. Ideas? Each list is also very very long.

```
    [i*j for i,j in zip(file3,file4)] 
    file3=[i.rstrip() for i in file3] file4=[i.rstrip() 
    for i in file4] [float(i)*float(j) for i,j in zip(file3,file4)]
```

Comment: Are the values actually in files? Or are they simply lists?

Comment: Why is this pointing at a dupe of another two dupes?  Don't make me bring out an over- and misused meme.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
[ i*j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

try this

```
file1=[i.rstrip() for i in file1]
file2=[i.rstrip() for i in file2]

[ float(i)*float(j) for i,j in zip(file1,file2)]
```

other way

```
for i,j in zip(file1,file2):
    out.write(float(i)*float(j) )
```

Comment: Damn is that code elegant.

Comment: I was just complementing your code. It is quite concise.

Comment: so I'm not sure if you meant taking that entire block of code and replacing it with urs? As in just have                                   [i*j for i,j in zip(file3,file4)]    
file3=[i.rstrip() for i in file3]    
file4=[i.rstrip() for i in file4]

[float(i)*float(j) for i,j in zip(file3,file4)]

Comment: @whuan0319 please write that in in ur question as edit so that i can understand it :)